# Add count/instance no. column to table (SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, gtfs

I have a table with the columns **car_id**, **stop_location**, **arrive_time** and **leave_time**. I'd like to add a column **stop_sequence**, which would start at 1 and increment by 1 for each row with the same **car_id** and then start again at 1 for the next **car_id** (when ordered by car_id, arrive_time).

It should look like this:

```
car_id    stop_lcn    arr_time    leave_time    stop_sequence

A         Home        --          0900          1
A         Shop        1000        1100          2
A         Work        1130        1700          3
B         Home        --          --            1
C         Home        --          0900          1
C         School      0930        1600          2
```

If anybody can tell me how I would go about adding this extra column I'd greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Why do you need to add a column? You can calculate stop_sequence as `row_number() over (partition by car_id order by leave_time) as stop_sequence`

Comment: Oh that's great! I didn't know that query... I still need to add the column because somebody else needs the table for a procedure that requires the 'stop_sequence' column.

Comment: I would let the other person know how to calculate it instead of adding the column. It can make the data not make sense with itself. Deleting or inserting a row for the existing groups would throw the sequence off. Just something to think about.

Comment: You probably have good reasons for what you are doing, I just want to point out the possibility to add a view over the table: `create view ... as select car_id,    stop_lcn,    arr_time,    leave_time, row_number() over (partition by car_id order by leave_time) as stop_sequence from T`. Now the procedure can use the view.

Comment: Thanks @Lennart - I'm up and running now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the analytic functions:

```
select c.*,
       row_number() over (partition by car_id order by leave_time) as stop_sequence
from cars c;
```

Actually, after writing this, I see than @Lennart has given this answer in the comments.  If that person answers the question, I will delete this answer.